# How to Install BPEL Feature 3.2.2 on Wso2 esb 4.5?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to install some features on `wso2 esb 4.5`. I have found an article about installing `BPEL Feature 3.2.2`, but when I try that I get the following errors. Does 'wso2 esb 4.5' support `BPEL`? Is there any documentation available?

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not 
be found. Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - BPEL Feature 3.2.2 
org.wso2.carbon.bpel.feature.group 3.2.2) Software currently installed: 
WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 4.0.0 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group 4.0.0) 
Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group 3.2.2) 
requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.server.feature.group [3.2.2,3.3.0)' 
but it could not be found Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar 3.2.0) 
WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar 3.2.1) 
WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 4.0.0 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar 4.0.0) 
WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar 3.2.2) 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - BPEL Feature 3.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.bpel.feature.group 3.2.2) 
To: org.wso2.carbon.bpel.server.feature.group [3.2.2] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - BPEL Core Feature 3.2.2 (org.wso2.carbon.bpel.server.feature.group 3.2.2) 
To: org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group [3.2.0,3.3.0) 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.0 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group 3.2.0) 
To: org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar [3.2.0] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 3.2.1 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group 3.2.1) 
To: org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar [3.2.1] 
Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Datasource Management Core Feature 4.0.0 (org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.group 4.0.0) 
To: org.wso2.carbon.datasource.server.feature.jar [4.0.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 which is released with Carbon version 3.2.3 and try to install features from online P2 repo. New BPEL features compatible with Carbon 4.0.0 (which is WSO2 ESB 4.5.0 is based on)is not released yet and will be released soon.